# epmd: got partial packet only on file descriptor 6 (0)

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, devops

I am getting this error on `rabbitmq-server`, when I restart it everything works but after sometimes I get the same error.

```
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-04-12 11:10:00 IST; 3 weeks 1 days ago
  Process: 616437 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl shutdown (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 616483 (beam.smp)
   Status: "Initialized"
    Tasks: 24 (limit: 11258)
   Memory: 774.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/rabbitmq-server.service
           ├─616483 /usr/lib64/erlang/erts-11.2/bin/beam.smp -W w -MBas ageffcbf -MHas ageffcbf -MBlmbcs 512 -MHlmbcs 512 -MMmcs 30 -P 1048576 -t 5000000 -stbt db -zdbbl 128000 -sbwt none -sbwtdcpu none -sbwtdi>
           ├─616500 erl_child_setup 32768
           ├─616525 /usr/lib64/erlang/erts-11.2/bin/epmd -daemon
           ├─616548 inet_gethost 4
           └─616549 inet_gethost 4

Apr 27 19:48:39 Project-Stage-NodeJS epmd[616525]: epmd: got partial packet only on file descriptor 6 (0)
Apr 27 20:45:13 Project-Stage-NodeJS epmd[616525]: epmd: got partial packet only on file descriptor 6 (0)
Apr 28 21:10:57 Project-Stage-NodeJS epmd[616525]: epmd: got partial packet only on file descriptor 6 (0)
Apr 30 02:46:08 Project-Stage-NodeJS epmd[616525]: epmd: got partial packet only on file descriptor 6 (0)
May 01 19:29:23 Project-Stage-NodeJS epmd[616525]: epmd: got partial packet only on file descriptor 6 (0)
May 02 23:25:14 Project-Stage-NodeJS epmd[616525]: epmd: error in read
May 03 00:30:47 Project-Stage-NodeJS epmd[616525]: epmd: got partial packet only on file descriptor 6 (0)
May 04 05:38:53 Project-Stage-NodeJS epmd[616525]: epmd: got partial packet only on file descriptor 6 (0)
May 04 10:51:02 Project-Stage-NodeJS epmd[616525]: epmd: error in read
May 05 09:07:56 Project-Stage-NodeJS epmd[616525]: epmd: got partial packet only on file descriptor 6 (0)
```